# Мягкий знак после шипящих в конце слова

Tags: орфография

Когда после шипящих на конце не ставится мягкий знак?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мягкий знак не ставится в прилагательных *(могуч, горюч)*; в существительных множественного числа *(задач, тысяч, плеч)*; в существительных второго склонения мужского рода *(ключ, плющ, плач)*; в наречиях и частицах только: *уж, замуж, невтерпеж*; в местоимении *наш*.